# Wrong item removed from Listbox

Tags: excel, vba

Items are transferred from ListBox1 to any of the 12 Listboxes (2-13), after items are selected and corresponding buttons are clicked.  Listboxes (2-13) can’t contain more than 8 items.

Problem: If items are selected from the middle of Listbox1 the code leaves the last selected item in Listbox1 and erroneously removes the top item from Listbox1 that wasn’t selected.  I’m not sure why. Please see screen shot and the code below:

Selected items in ListBox1:

[image]

Outcome after 'left arrow' button is pressed:(testtwo.A.2F item has disappeared and testseven.A.2R item remains in ListBox1.

[image]

Code for 'left' and 'right' buttons:

```
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr



End Sub
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()

   Dim iCtr As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim arr(8) As Long

        For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True And Not ListBox2.ListCount = 8 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
                i = i + 1
                arr(i) = iCtr
            End If

          If i = 8 Then Exit For
        Next iCtr

        For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
         Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem arr(j)
        Next

End Sub
```

Listbox1 is fmMultiSelectExtended and Listboxes 2-13 are fmMultiSelectMulti.

Thank you.

Comment: just change the order: cut this line `i = i +1` and paste it after this line `arr(i) = iCtr`,(i changed my answer, sorry about this)

Comment: no problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
   For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
```

It doesn't look like it should be decremented as it's accessing `arr` not the list. Try:

```
   For j = i To 1 Step -1
```

Comment: now I get "run time error 9, script out of range" here `Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem arr(j)` Thanks

Comment: Actually, on second thought, I'm not sure this matters. You may just have an empty `arr(0)` in every case.

Comment: What's the value of `j` when that happens? At any rate, I'd step through using F8 and look at the values of `arr` in the Locals Window. You've got a classic "off-by-one" error and `arr` looks like the best suspect to me.

Comment: `For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
         Debug.Print j
         Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem arr(j)` gives me 2, 1, 0

Comment: Wait, I think I see another possibility. Try changing `For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1` to `For j = i To 1 Step -1`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. One last thought is to name `arr` to something more descriptive. You'll be glad you did when you go back six months from now :-)